# Inflate customize ListView inside AsyncTask class from json api

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

How i can inflate a customized **ListView** from a **Json** API by using **AsyncTask** ?

Before , i can inflate a **ListView** from **sqlite** by usign **CursorAdapter** class.

And i know about **AsyncTask** and it's methods and lifecycle.

> But know i can't understand how i can do fetching data from a **json**
>   by **AsyncTask** and use result array to show in a custom **Listview**
>   included image and text ....

Comment: do you know about onPostExecute() and about  json objects.

Comment: yes . but i can't know how to use onPostExecute() to get json results and show in custom Listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you do it on the ui thread here is a quick example is just illustrative but it should give you what you are looking for

```
private class RequestJson extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {     
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         ((YourActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 // Here is where you have to do all ui operations
                 // The next lines are just examples
                 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                 ListView myListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view);

                 myContainer.add(myListView);
            }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: why used this <URL, Integer, Long> in AsyncTask ?
and say me about myContainer in  **myContainer.add(myListView);**

Comment: mmm like I was saying is just an example I am guessing you already have your asynctask, so pretty much I am asuming after you made your request to get your json you are not able to inflate your view. If is that case it  usually means that you are trying to make UI changes under  a thread that cannot hit UI. Saying that the new lisview needs to be set into the uiThread in order to get your ui changes reflected. Let me know if you also need the request example and I can change my answer. myContainer is your View that will contain the ListView